# How can i center vertically this background with the text inside?

Tags: css, text, center, vertical-alignment

I'm  trying to center vertically the background-color of these texts.
[I see this way only on mobile devices:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKEfS.jpg)
I see it properly on my computer. I'm also using a @font-face gotham font-family. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/demiancurutchet/54mw8gs2/11/

CSS:

```
.title {
color: #D4145A;
line-height: 1.5;
color: #333;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 2rem;
width: 100%;}
.title span {
width: fit-content;
display: inline-block;
padding: 5px 10px;
align-items: center;}
.bg-violet {
background-color: #662D91;
color:#fff;}
```

HTML:

```
<h1 class="title">
    Tu empresa va a <br>
    <span class="bg-violet">incrementar</span> sus <span class="bg-violet">ingresos</span>
</h1>
```

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this if you wanted like this...**

```css
.title {
color: #D4145A;
line-height: 1.5;
color: #333;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 2rem;
text-align:center;
width: 100%;}
.title span {
width: fit-content;
display: inline-block;
padding: 5px 10px;
}
.bg-violet {
background-color: #662D91;
color:#fff;}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">
    Tu empresa va a <br>
    <span class="bg-violet">incrementar</span> sus <span class="bg-violet">ingresos</span>
</h1>
```